# Running the development web server google app engine for php

Tags: php, google-app-engine, python-2.7

Where can I write the following command 
i am following the developer tutorial for simple hello world script [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld)

`google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=pathto-php-cgi path-to-your-app`
When I run application in google app launcher I get a error message . I have WAMP install and it is running fine.
`The path specified with the --php_exectuable_path flag () does not exist.`

Php path - c:\php\php-cgi.exe

Comment: What is the path to your php cgi executeable? If you don't know what that is or where it is in Wamp, please contact the vendor of Wamp for your support options first. They should have documentation materials available for you online.

Comment: Why I am getting error in browser `php_exectuable_path flag () does not exist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also met this problem, and it has been solved.
for example,

```
      if your PHP folder is E:/sam/php/

      if your PHP site folder is F:/mysite/facebook/

      if your dev_appserver.py is under E:/whatever/
```

I'm not sure how to change googleapplauncher.exe configurations, instead, you have to use cmd instead.  I think this exe has config files but I did not find it.  Open the command window and go to folder E:/whatever/ to run "python" command under this folder.
    Type in:

```
      python dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=E:/sam/php/php-cgi.exe F:/mysite/facebook/

      NOTE: REMEMBER to type "php-cgi.exe"
            use slash
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which is the name of the file in Windows, but i just have that problem, the full path from / for your php-cgi54.exe including the fullname of the file and then the full path from / of your folder.

I also run it like admin so check if your cmd or terminal was open with admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

@Chander if you have wamp running you need to select a different listening port for app engine by typing the command: --port=9999 for example.

Here's what worked for me:

1. Open your cmd, make sure you're in the same directory as your sdk.
2. Type: "google_appengine/dev_appserver.py" --port=9999 --php_executable_path="fullpath\php-cgi.exe" "helloworld/"
3. If you have another local server like xampp or wamp,make sure you use the --port command to select another listening port as shown above.
4. Press enter and you should have your helloworld script working.